# Dynamic Search of a Response through Streams

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have the following response from my API:

```
[
 {
  "country":"INDIA",
  "region": "Asia",
  "doorNo": "12",
  "pinCode": "345"
 }, 
 {
  "country":"Angolia",
  "region": "Asia",
  "doorNo": "13",
  "pinCode": "789"
 }, 
 {
  "country":"Nigeria",
  "region": "Australia",
  "doorNo": "15",
  "pinCode": "947"
 }
]
```

I have to search this response dynamically by country and region.
For example, when I search for `[country: INDIA, region: Asia]`, I would expect the result:

```
{
  "country":"INDIA",
  "region": "Asia",
  "doorNo": "12",
  "pinCode": "345"
 }
```

However, I´m getting the following result ('*or*' condition instead of '*and*'):

```
{
  "country":"INDIA",
  "region": "Asia",
  "doorNo": "12",
  "pinCode": "345"
 }, 
 {
  "country":"Angolia",
  "region": "Asia",
  "doorNo": "13",
  "pinCode": "789"
 },
```

Is there any way by streams to achieve this.

**I've tried the following approach:**

```
response=response.stream().filter(x-> x.getCountry().equals(country) ||
         x.getRegion().equls(region) || x.getDoorNo().equals(doorNo) ||
         x.getPinCode().equals(pinCode));
```

When the search input is `[countryName=India, region=Asia]`, I'm getting the following result:

```
{ "country":"INDIA", "region": "Asia", "doorNo": "12", "pinCode": "345" }, 
{ "country":"Angolia", "region": "Asia", "doorNo": "13", "pinCode": "789" }
```

However, the result I'm expecting is:

```
{ "country":"INDIA", "region": "Asia", "doorNo": "12", "pinCode": "345" }
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the exact match of the response of any input given. Instead of having the or condition

Comment: `I am having the below as result` - The code you've posted isn't capable to produce any result, because it would not compile. Share the actual code you're running, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Can you suggest me a way to get the expected result through streams

Comment: Wait, from the snippet you've posted it's even not clear what should be the of `response`. On the right side of the assignment you have a `Stream` because `stream().filter()` produces a stream. Please hare the code that we can copy into ide and run.

Comment: Also provide a dummy `class` that reflect the shape of objects in the stream.

Comment: @Shilpa, would you be able to share class structure of `Response`? that will helps us to provide error free suggestion

Comment: Please, don't ignore suggestions. `response=response.stream().filter()` would not even compile. How can we give an answer while we can't reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```java
response
.stream()
.filter(x -> (x.getCountry().equals(country) && x.getRegion().equals(region)));
```

use a specific condition or you could use multiple filters,

```java
response
.stream()
.filter(x -> (x.getCountry().equals(country)))
.filter(x.getRegion().equals(region) || x.getDoorNo().equals(doorNo) || x.getPinCode().equals(pinCode));
```